# How can I get the average difference between the max and min dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get the **average** number of months difference between two dates:

```
select client_id, 
        avg(12*(year(MAX(received_date))-year(min(received_date))) 
        + MONTH(MAX(received_date))-MONTH(min(received_date)))
        from tmpTwoAccessions
        group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
```

I am getting this message:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Can you please advise me on what am I doing incorrectly here?
Thanks so much for your guidance.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the difference between the MAX and MIN in a sub-query, and then average that in the outer query.

```
SELECT client_id, AVG(delta_date)
  FROM (SELECT client_id, patient_id,
               12 * (YEAR(MAX(received_date))-YEAR(MIN(received_date))) 
               + MONTH(MAX(received_date)) - MONTH(MIN(received_date))) AS delta_date
          FROM tmpTwoAccessions
         GROUP BY client_id, patient_id
       ) AS x
 GROUP BY client_id;
```

I'm not convinced your date difference expression is optimal, but I've not tried changing it.

---

[Yurly Rozhovetskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360171/yuriy-rozhovetskiy) suggested the expression:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(received_date), MAX(received_date))
```

which looks good to me.  The revised query becomes:

```
SELECT client_id, AVG(delta_date)
  FROM (SELECT client_id, patient_id,
               DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(received_date), MAX(received_date)) AS delta_date
          FROM tmpTwoAccessions
         GROUP BY client_id, patient_id
       ) AS x
 GROUP BY client_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a subquery like this:

```
select
    T.client_id
    ,avg(T.ReceivedDateDiff)
from 
(
    select client_id, 
    (12*(year(MAX(received_date))-year(min(received_date))) 
        + MONTH(MAX(received_date))-MONTH(min(received_date))) AS ReceivedDateDiff
    from tmpTwoAccessions
    group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
)
T
GROUP BY client_id
```

Comment: DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(received_date), MAX(received_date))

Answer (score 2):

Would be cleaner to implement with DATEDIFF.

```
WITH tmpTwoAccessionsMonths AS(         
    select 
          client_id
        , PATIENT_ID
        , DATEDIFF(month,MIN(received_date),MAX(received_date)) MonthDifference
    from 
        tmpTwoAccessions
    group by 
        CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
)
SELECT
    client_id
    ,AVG(MonthDifference)
FROM
    tmpTwoAccessionsMonths
GROUP BY
    client_id
```